# Connecting to EWS on production environment using ews-java-api-2.0 not working

Tags: exchangewebservices, connection-timeout

I need to send email to microsoft exchange server through EWS. It is working fine at my local and uat environments even with proxies as well. But somehow it is not working on production. Please check the exception below.

[image]

I cross checked that all ports are opened at the environment.

I have prepared one small program to get the exception. Please find the code below. There is no problem with authentication. All provided values are correct.
Also proxy is not enabled on production env.

```
public class emailTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out
            .println("******************Inside emailTest*************************");

    try {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream input = null;
        input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
        prop.load(input);
        String userName = "xxxxx@xxx.com";
        String passWord = "xxxxx";
        String domain = "domain.com";
        String proxyName = "PROXYNAME";
        String proxyport = "PROXYPORT";
        String url = "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx";
        String tolist = "xxxxx@xxx.com";
        String from = "xxxxx@xxx.com";
        String ccList = "xxxxx@xxx.com";
        System.out.println("Initailizing credentials");
        if (userName != null && passWord != null && domain != null) {
            ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(
                    userName, passWord);

            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(
                    ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
            System.out.println("Initializing Service ");

            System.out.println("Setting credentials");
            service.setUseDefaultCredentials(true);
            service.setCredentials(credentials);
            if (proxyName != null) {
                WebProxy WebRequest = new WebProxy(proxyName,
                        Integer.parseInt(proxyport));
                service.setWebProxy(WebRequest);
            }
            service.setUrl(new URI(url));

            // service.autodiscoverUrl("xxxx@xxx.com");

            EmailMessage mail = new EmailMessage(service);
            mail.setSubject("Test Mail Exchange Service");
            mail.setBody(new MessageBody(
                    "Test Mail Exchange Service -Mail body"));

            System.out.println("Adding Receipents");
            for (String to : tolist.split(";")) {
                mail.getToRecipients().add(new EmailAddress(to));
            }
            for (String cc : ccList.split(";")) {
                mail.getCcRecipients().add(new EmailAddress(cc));
            }
            mail.setFrom(new EmailAddress(from));
            System.out.println("Sending Mail ");
            mail.sendAndSaveCopy();

            System.out.println("Sent Successfully");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please configure username,password,domain");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Execption ************ " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}

}
```

**Please help me with this as it is on production environment.**

Comment: Have you already tried to connect using the [EWS-Editor](https://github.com/dseph/EwsEditor)? If you get a time out using it, it's probably independent of your code.

Comment: One thing I just spotted: `service.setUseDefaultCredentials(true);` Since you're providing the credentials explicit, this shouldn't be set to `true`. But this is probably not the reason of your problem, as you are calling on the next line `service.setCredentials(credentials);` which will switch to the appropriate mode.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't access EWS-Editor ...

Comment: What do you mean? You cannot open the website? Or you cannot access the mailbox using EWS-Editor?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I misunderstood your statement about EWS-Editor. I will check with it. Thanks.

Comment: @LuCio  I checked with .net team and they are able to connect with ews without any failure.   Moreover, I got the exception like **ServiceRequestException** whcih means there is some problem with client while sending the request. What can it be ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the ews-java-api itself.

For more information, you could refer to this link:

[ews-java-api java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out for https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28740579/ews-java-api-java-net-connectexception-connection-timed-out-for-https)

Answer (score 0):

Try this dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.ws/jaxws-api -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
            </dependency>
```